# Match linux kernel headers / kernel version? 4.9.0-5-amd64 kernel / 4.9.0-11 headers -- guestadditions vbox

Tags: linux, virtualbox, debian, guest-additions

I am guessing that a new thing with Virtual Box / vbox version 6.14 is the insistence that

> Note
> The running kernel and the kernel header files must be updated to matching versions.

(see https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#externalkernelmodules)

The problem I have is that the kernel version of the Debian distro that I have been using fine in other virtual machines is 4.9.0-5-amd64 (kernel) but the header files, which came with the distro, are 4.9.0-11 (headers).

Now I am trying to install guest additions but the VBoxLin.... etc script won't run because it says that the header and distro versions must match. I have previously installed the exact same distro with VBox version 6.12 with no problem.

So I have searched for kernal header files - ultimately searching

https://snapshot.debian.org/package/linux/

but cannot fin the headers anywhere - the closest that I can find in the snapshot is 4.9.0-rc5

so I think my solution may be to try to find VBox 6.12, but not sure.

Any suggestions gratefully received.

For info the distro is chrunchbangplusplus and I have used it with vbox successfully with multiple host operating systems for several years with close to zero issues.. hosts have included windows 10 and MacOS high sierra, mojave and now attempting to install on Catalina...

Comment: Have you tried updating the Kernel in your Debian system?  https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/get-linux-kernel-5-3-on-debian-10-stable/  I have Kernel 5.7 in Kali and 5.8 in Ubuntu and I find VMware Tools install without issue. That may fix your other post as well. Worth considering.

Comment: @John - hey many thanks for the useful comment - yes updating the kernel to a version with matching headers should fix this issue and at this point I am prepared to try anything. Do you want to turn that into an answer? You would immediately get upvote plus the green tick if it works...

Comment: I posted an answer for you. Thank you.

Comment: @tom Regarding the other question that should have been closed, you should just delete the question in cases like this. All good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating the Kernel in your Debian system?

https://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/get-linux-kernel-5-3-on-debian-10-stable/

I have Kernel 5.7 in Kali and 5.8 in Ubuntu and I find VMware Tools install without issue. That may fix your other post as well. This should work for you.

Key points of the Kernel update are listed below from the article posted.

> If you’d like to get version 5.3, which is (as of writing this)To
> upgrade to the most recent stable release of the Linux kernel, you
> will need to set up the Debian Backports repository on the system.
> That is described in the article.
>
> Installing Kernel 5.3 on Debian 10 Stable Since we’ve enabled the
> Debian Backports repository on the system, there are no special hoops
> to jump through to get Linux Kernel 5.3 up and running. Instead, we
> can install everything right from the software repositories. Follow
> the instructions below to get 5.3 up and running on your Debian 10
> system.
>
> Debian Desktop installation
>
> Using the apt command in the terminal, load up Linux Kernel 5.3 on
> your Debian 10 Stable desktop.
>
> sudo apt install linux-image-5.3.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 Additionally, be sure
> to install the 5.3 Linux Kernel headers, if you rely on modules.
>
> sudo apt install linux-headers-5.3.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 Debian Server
> installation Need to get Linux Kernel 5.3 working on Debian Server? Do
> the following.
>
> First, determine whether you need the 5.3 cloud kernel or the 5.3
> desktop kernel. Then, use the apt install command to load it up on the
> system.
>
> sudo apt install linux-image-5.3.0-0.bpo.2-cloud-amd64

Comment: many thanks I will try this out and if it works... the green tick will be coming your way :-).   sorry afk for last hour

Comment: thank you this worked, didn't know that the kernel could be upgraded this way. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the update and I was happy to assist you.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have done as you suggested.